# I am the smallest of my relatives

Tags: riddle

> I am the smallest of my relatives. But I get far more care.
>
> I dream of their freedom but tradition keeps me in place.
>
> Different to my relatives I bring pleasure on two different ways.
>
> I am forced to look natural in an unnatural way.

What am I?

Comment: No problem. I see you fixed the first line; I've fixed the title to match.

Comment: pleasure on two different ways? or in two different ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> A bonsai tree
> You are smallest of the trees and get cared for.
> You dream of the freedom of growth that normal trees have but are kept in place by your caretaker.
> While your relatives might bring pleasure with fruits, you bring visual pleasure and the pleasure of a hobby to your caretaker.
> Your caretaker forces you to look like a natural tree by trimming you with unnatural ways.

Comment: Nice! Hope you liked my first riddle

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer?

> > 0

I am the smallest of my relatives. But I get far more care.

> > It is the smallest of it's (natural) relatives and when dealing with 0 you need to take care because sometimes arithmetic operations on 0 will lead to infinites and NaNs

I dream of their freedom but tradition keeps me in place.

> > Other numbers can be used in any arithmetic operation, and while plotting you can shorten the axis with a break, but the origin will always be constant (0,0)

Different to my relatives I bring pleasure on two different ways.

> > 0 demarcates the x-axis and y-axis

I am forced to look natural in an unnatural way.

> > 0 is not considered as a natural number but alternately it is considered as a natural number when taking the definition in the context of non-negative integers

Answer (score 0):

> Cat - Relatives are Wild cats. Cats are smaller than Wild Cats, somewhat domesticated so less free. Bring Pleasure to humans by being their pet, and maybe by getting rid of vermin? Some owners dress their pets up. EDIT: To be clear by Wild cats I mean Big Cats like Tiger, Leopard etc.. EDIT 2 - I didn't explicitly point out that pet cats of course get more care from their owners than their Big cat relatives.

Comment: Good try! But I am not a cat

Comment: Doh! That last bit with the natural unnatural way just didn't quite fit properly